# How to access to Sails config variable in Tasks files

Tags: javascript, config, sails.js

I have in **tasks/config/custom.js**:

```js
module.exports = function(grunt) {
    /* code */
    grunt.loadNpmTasks(sails.config.mywebsite.foo);
};
```

> sails.config.mywebsite.foo

But when calling a configuration variable, Sails shows me an error of GruntFile.

I think that in these files can not access the configuration variables. But, How I can access them here?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You need to lift sails first:

```
var Sails = require('sails');

module.exports = function(grunt) {
  grunt.registerTask('foo', 'Foo tast', function() {
    var done = this.async();

    Sails.lift({}, function() {
      console.log(sails.config.mywebsite.foo);

      done();
    })
  });
};
```